# Does MFC CList support the copy assignment?

Tags: c++, mfc, clist

I've looked up the CList definition in MSVC [`afxtempl.h`](http://www.cppdoc.com/example/mfc/classdoc/MFC/AFXTEMPL.H.html) and document on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/bxde0zae.aspx). I did not see the `CList& operator=(const CList&);` is defined.

Can I directly use `operator=` to copy a CList object like this?

```
 CList<int> a = b;
```

Or I should iterate the source CList manually from `head` to `tail` and `AddTail` on the target CList?

```
 for(POSITION pos = a.HeadPosition(); pos; )
 {
      const auto& item = a.GetNext(pos);
      b.AddTail(item);
 }
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the copy assignment operator isn't defined, then it isn't defined and can't be used. That's true for `CList`, as you've already observed, so no, you can't just use `operator=` to copy a `CList` object. If you want a deep copy of the collection, you will need to write a function to do so manually.

But consider whether you really want a deep copy. Most of the time, you'll want to pass collection types by reference, rather than by value. This is especially true in MFC, where they can contain objects derived from `CObject` that can't necessarily be copied. In fact, you'll notice that copying is explicitly disallowed by the `CObject` class, using a private copy constructor and assignment operator:

```
   // Disable the copy constructor and assignment by default so you will get
   //   compiler errors instead of unexpected behaviour if you pass objects
   //   by value or assign objects.
private:
   CObject(const CObject& objectSrc);              // no implementation
   void operator=(const CObject& objectSrc);       // no implementation
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, does MFC provide any helper function to copy the CList? Or I need to make a custom function to copy?

Comment: No, there's no helper function. You have the right idea already of iterating through the list.