# Passing CList variable gives error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member

Tags: c++, clist

In My class, I've a static `Clist variable` declared in the following way:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <afxtempl.h>
void otherfunc(CList<int,int> a)
{

}
class A
{
public:
CList<int,int> myvariable;
void myfunc()
{
otherfunc(myvariable);
}

};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;
    a.myfunc();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

`otherfunc()` is not part of my class.

Where am I going wrong?
I have just pasted the code snippet with the problem. I have initiated it and everything works file except for the line where im calling otherfunc(). Its has no dependence over static keyword. Even if i remove static, i get the same error.

Edited : Here is the error tht I get :

```
C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtempl.h(776) : error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(561) : see declaration of 'CObject::CObject'
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(532) : see declaration of 'CObject'
1>        This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'CList<TYPE,ARG_TYPE>::CList(const CList<TYPE,ARG_TYPE> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            TYPE=int,
1>            ARG_TYPE=int
1>        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it is doesn't compile (`Class` should be `class`, `Public` should be `public` etc). What is the error message? Also you must post a simple compilable example that reproduce your error. My guess is that you didn't instantiate your static variable outside its class declaration, see

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/

Comment: @230490 please post the full error message/code at least, otherwise we can only guess what's happening. In your code snippet, there is no private variable.

Comment: I created a sample which can be copy pasted to a project  to reproduce the error im facing

Comment: @230490 where are you calling `otherfunc` in your snippet above?

Comment: Inside myfunc() . I missed to remove the commented part

Comment: @230490 is `CList` copy-constructible? I.e., does `CList` have a copy constructor? If not, then you cannot pass by value in `otherfunc(Clist<int, int> a)`, and need to pass the `CList` by reference `otherfunc(Clist<int, int>& a)`, as passing by value invokes the copy constructor.

Comment: Yup, Just realized it! Thanks a tonne!!

Answer (score 0):

You may not get the error because of "Public:". Because "Public:" is not a key word it's a label. That's why "myvariable" is private by default.
Instead  of "Public:" use "public:" and also replace  "Static" with static.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the definition of -

```
void otherfunc(CList<int,int> a)
```

The input parameter `CList<int,int> a`  is passed by value, this means that when you call this function it will copy the input parameter by using `CList<int,int>` Copy Constructor.
But `CList<int,int>` does not implement a Copy Constructor, and its base class `CObject` define its Copy Constructor as private.

You should change the definition to -

```
void otherfunc(CList<int,int>& a)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210250/does-mfc-clist-support-the-copy-assignment